# GridView custom spacing issue

Tags: android, view, grid

Good day. I have a gridView with 24 images. I have 3 rows,8 columns. Columns should be separated by 4x4, so 4 columns and SPACE and then the another 4 columns. Problem is that i get lots of unwanted issues. First i tried with `verticalSpacing` but that purely not needed as it spaces full items of grid view,but i only need to have space between 8 columns(4x4).So i tried to give a top margin dynamically in code to my single image view whenever my position will reach the items i want to be spaced.so i did it with this code in my adapter.`

```
   if (position >= 12 && position <= 14) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.topMargin = 50;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }`
```

This works.But problem is that the image views which have been spaced got squeezed  a lot and its looks so ugly.So by googling i found purely nothing even closer to my situation.Please can you help me out and tell me what i can do to have spaces only between items i want without squeezing them.

Here is xml for grid view layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_background_color"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_grid_view"
        android:background="#dfd8d8"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/arrange_poster_info_button"
            style="@style/PrimaryButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/info"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code for single item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imagesHolderFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/stripsSingleimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:siRadius="0dp"
        app:siBorderWidth="1dp"
        app:siBorderColor="#ffffff"
        app:siSquare="true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/selection_overlay" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here ill add link to image where my images squeezed and looking so ugly.
[As you can see,the first items of second row got squeezed

http://crm.socialobjects.am/attachments/7811/Screenshot_2015-12-08-10-09-28.png

Comment: simple answer: wrap your single item Framelayout in a vertical LinearLayout, add a view with height 50 at bottom and make its visibility gone unless position is between 12 and 14.

Comment: hmm ok lemme give it a try

Comment: ok i tried and surely it worked,buts this is kinda ugly way of workaround..but stilll works!